# I cannot see the value of CString in VS2015. What should I do to see it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 2. I modified some settings days ago and today I found I can't see the value of CString. All I saw was {ATL::CStringT > >}

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Below is the snapshot.
[image]

Comment: Could you print screen that?

Comment: The watch shows what I saw for the CString sTempPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this exact issue with Visual Studio 2015 for CLI C++ projects.  You need to check Debugging->General-> Use Managed Compatibility Mode.

[image: Checkbox]

Comment: It fixed my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Great!  This was an annoying bug for us as well.